# Can Kafka Streams interact with external systems?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

I’d like to use Kafka Streams, but also interact with external databases and APIs. I’ve read that it is recommended to do so by using Kafka Connect, but I wonder how and why. Is it possible to query a database (even if it doesn’t have a Kafka Connect connector) and an API for each record even with Kafka Streams? Or shall I use another processing engine for this use case?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing stopping you from making an external API call.

The recommendation to use Kafka Connect is the following

- Don't reinvent the wheel; there's fault tolerance built into Connect API
- Streams API is very sensitive to time, especially when joining topics. Every method that you use adds latency, and potential missed events

Sure, you can use other frameworks like Spark, Flink, Nifi, etc. depending on what you really need to do.

Writing your own Connector is not much different than your own Streams job. Only the deployment model is different.